# PIG query to pivot rows and columns with count of like rows

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-pig

Trying to create sql or PIG queries that will yield a count of distinct values results based on type.

In other words, given this table:

```
Type:    Value:
A        x
B        y
C        y
B        y
C        z
A        x
A        z
A        z
A        x
B        x
B        z
B        x
C        x
```

I want to get the following results:

```
Type:    x:    y:    z:
A         3     0     2
B         2     2     1
C         1     1     1
```

Additionally, a table of averages as a result would be helpful too

```
Type:    x:    y:    z:
A         0.60  0.00  0.40
B         0.40  0.40  0.20 
C         0.33  0.33  0.33
```

**EDIT 4**

I am a nooby at PIG, but reading 8 different stack overflow posts I came up with this.

When I use this PIG query

```
A = LOAD 'tablex' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
x = foreach A GENERATE id_orig_h;
xx = distinct x;
y = foreach A GENERATE id_resp_h;
yy = distinct y;
yyy = group yy all;
zz = GROUP A BY (id_orig_h, id_resp_h);
B = CROSS xx, yy;
C = foreach B generate xx::id_orig_h as id_orig_h, yy::id_resp_h as id_resp_h;
D = foreach zz GENERATE flatten (group) as (id_orig_h, id_resp_h), COUNT(A) as count;
E = JOIN C by (id_orig_h, id_resp_h) LEFT OUTER, D BY (id_orig_h, id_resp_h);
F = foreach E generate C::id_orig_h as id_orig_h, C::id_resp_h as id_resp_h, D::count as count;
G = foreach yyy generate 0 as id:chararray, flatten(BagToTuple(yy));
H = group F by id_orig_h;
I = foreach H generate group as id_orig_h, flatten(BagToTuple(F.count)) as count;
dump G;
dump I;
```

Sort of works.......

I get this:

```
(0,x,y,z)
(A,3,0,2)
(B,2,2,1)
(C,1,1,1)
```

Which I can import to a text file strip the "(" and ")" and use as a CSV with schema being first line.  This sort of works it is **SO SLOW**. I would like a nicer, faster, cleaner way of doing this.  If anyone out there knows of a way please let me know.

Comment: Do you know the list of values?

Comment: The first table is good representation, but the values may vary from day to day it wont always be x,y,z it could be 3 values or 900.

Comment: Suggestion - please update the question title. Its not clear and helpful for other folks.

Comment: Suggestions for change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = LOAD 'tablex' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
x = foreach A GENERATE id_orig_h;
xx = distinct x;
y = foreach A GENERATE id_resp_h;
yy = distinct y;
yyy = group yy all;
zz = GROUP A BY (id_orig_h, id_resp_h);
B = CROSS xx, yy;
C = foreach B generate xx::id_orig_h as id_orig_h, yy::id_resp_h as id_resp_h;
D = foreach zz GENERATE flatten (group) as (id_orig_h, id_resp_h), COUNT(A) as count;
E = JOIN C by (id_orig_h, id_resp_h) LEFT OUTER, D BY (id_orig_h, id_resp_h);
F = foreach E generate C::id_orig_h as id_orig_h, C::id_resp_h as id_resp_h, D::count as count;
G = foreach yyy generate 0 as id:chararray, flatten(BagToTuple(yy));
H = group F by id_orig_h;
I = foreach H generate group as id_orig_h, flatten(BagToTuple(F.count)) as count;
dump G;
dump I;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of would work only with Oracle, and although it wouldn't provide you with a column for each value, it would present you the data like this:

```
A   x=3,y=3,z=3
B   x=4,y=3
C   y=3,z=2
```

of course if you have 900 values it would show:

```
A  x=3,y=6,...,ff=12
```

etc...

I'm not able to add comment so I can't ask you if oracle is ok. Anyway here's the query that would achieve that:

```
SELECT type, values FROM 
(SELECT type, SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(value || '=' || OCC, ','),2) values, seq, 
MAX(seq) OVER (partition by type) max
FROM
(SELECT type, value, OCC, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (partition by type ORDER BY type, value) seq
FROM
(SELECT type, value, COUNT(*) OCC
FROM tableName
GROUP BY type, value))
START WITH seq=1
CONNECT by PRIOR
  seq+1=seq
  AND PRIOR 
    type=type)
WHERE seq = max;
```

For the Average you need to add the information before all the rest, here's the code:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT type, 
SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(value || '=' || OCC, ','),2) values,
SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(value || '=' || (OCC / TOT), ','),2) average, 
seq, MAX(seq) OVER (partition by type) max
FROM
(SELECT type, value, TOT, OCC, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (partition by type ORDER BY type, value) seq
FROM
(
SELECT type, value, TOT, COUNT(*) OCC
FROM (SELECT type, value, COUNT(*) OVER (partition by type) TOT
FROM tableName)
GROUP BY type, value, TOT
))
START WITH seq=1
CONNECT by PRIOR
  seq+1=seq
  AND PRIOR 
    type=type)
WHERE seq = max;
```

Comment: I am not using oracle at the moment, I am using hadoop hive.  I tried the query anyway, just in case and I got an error saying that - sub-query was not supported.  Upon further investigation I found out that Hive does not support sub-queries outside of the FROM clause. I only have access to HIVE or PIG at the moment.

Comment: SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH is only in oracle (and it's the function that make everything possible). I can check if there's anything similar in HIVE, but I'm no expert of it

Answer (score 0):

Updated code according to Edit#3 in question:

```
A = load '/path/to/input/file' using AvroStorage();
B = group A by (type, value);
C = foreach B generate flatten(group) as (type, value), COUNT(A) as count;

-- Now get all the values.
M = foreach A generate value;

-- Left Outer Join all the values with C, so that every type has exactly same number of values associated
N = join M by value left outer, C by value;
O = foreach N generate 
                  C::type as type, 
                  M::value as value, 
                  (C::count == null ? 0 : C::count) as count; --count = 0 means value was not associated with the type
P = group O by type;
Q = foreach P {
                  R = order O by value asc;  --Ordered by value, so values counts are ordered consistently in all the rows.
                  generate group as type, flatten(R.count);
              }
```

Please note that I did not execute the code above. These are just the representational steps.

Comment: Gaurav,
Thanks for the help, I got an error, I could not post it here because it looked funky. I edited my original post, please take a look there for my comment to you.

Comment: Gaurav,I managed to get some of this working but the "group as (type, value)" part of the third line is breaking it.  When I omot "as (type, value)"  I get it to work with the third line being modified to: "C = foreach B generate group, COUNT(A);". This returns a table that looks like this ((type,value),Count).  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, my code had a bug. Fixed it now. Specifically, it should be flatten(group) and not group in third line. Hope this helps.

Comment: Gaurav, This is very close but still no exactly what I need. take a look at my last edit please.

Comment: I've updated the code accordingly. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the vector operation UDF's in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse )  Consider that each 'value' is a dimension in a very high dimension space. You can interpret a single value instance as a vector in that dimension, with value 1.  In Hive, we would represent such a vector simply as a map with a string as the key, and an int or other numeric as the value.

What you want to create is a vector which is the sum of all vectors, grouped by type.  The query would be :

```
SELECT type, 
  union_vector_sum( map( value, 1 ) ) as vector,
FROM table
GROUP BY type;
```

Brickhouse even has a normalize function, which will produce your 'averages'

```
SELECT type, 
  vector_normalize(union_vector_sum( map( value, 1 ) ))
     as normalized_vector,
FROM table
GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: Jerome,
I tried, it took me some time to get it all working but i finally was able to run the query. When I ran it i got a result close to what I want, but is there a way to instead of having a vector as a column, having the values be the columns, with each count underneath?

Comment: Wow, that's great.  To make columns out of the vector, use the `map_index' UDF. You need to know what the columns are ahead of them, of course, since a Hive table has the same columns for all rows.